# mongodump error on Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: mongodb, macos, macos-sierra, mongodump, mongorestore

I tried to dump a tiny database for testing purposes using the following command:

```
mongodump --db demo
```

There was no output, but after around half an hour I got multiple error messages in my console:

```
...
fatal error: systemstack called from unexpected goroutine
fatal error: systemstack called from unexpected goroutine
fatal error: systemstack called from unexpected goroutine
fatal error: systemstack called from unexpected goroutine
fatal error: systemstack called from unexpected goroutine
fatal error: systemstack called from unexpected goroutine
fatal error: systemstack called from unexpected goroutine
fatal error: systemstack called from unexpected goroutine
fatal error: systemstack called from unexpected goroutine
...
```

Not sure what does it mean, any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Go into mongo exec 'show dbs' and verify demo is indeed tiny.  Also, ensure the version of mongodump is >= mongod.   
You might also have a monstrously deeply nested doc in there, e.g.:  {a: {a: {a: {a: {a: {a: {a: .....

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem was in mongo/go versions. I just upgraded mongo from brew and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem. Fixed it with:

`brew upgrade mongodb`

Comment: Thanks you kind sir!